# Entity and year fixed effects, and entity clustering, with panel data in R

Tags: r, panel-data, plm

I am trying to make three regressions:

1. Regression of dem_ind on log_gdppc (standing for democracy index and logarithm of gdp per capita), with standard errors clustered across countries to correct for autocorrelation.
2. The above, but also counting fixed effects of entity (in this case, country).
3. The above, but also counting fixed effects of entity and year.

I have the following two regressions:

Firstly, what I believe is #2 above, counting fixed effects of country:

```
library(plm)
library(lmtest)
library(multiwayvcov)
library(dplyr)
library(lmtest)
library(sandwich)



regdii <- plm(dem_ind ~ log_gdppc,
           data = ID,
           index = c("country", "year"),
           model = "within")

coeftest(regdii, vcov. = vcovHC, type = "HC1")

# t test of coefficients:

#          Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
# log_gdppc 0.083741   0.031421  2.6652 0.007849 **
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

And secondly, what I believe is #3, counting fixed effects of country and year:

```
regdv <- plm(dem_ind ~ log_gdppc,
              data = ID,
              index = c("country", "year"),
              model = "within",
              effect = "twoways")

coeftest(regdv, vcov = vcovHC, type = "HC1")

# t test of coefficients:

#          Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
# log_gdppc 0.053588   0.042113  1.2725   0.2036
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I have two questions.

1. Are these regressions fixed effect panel models, one counting fixed effect of country, the other counting country and year, with clustered standard errors?
2. How do I do a non-fixed effect model, clustering over entity (in this case country)?

I have researched on other sites. What I have here is mostly adjusted from this https://www.econometrics-with-r.org/10-3-fixed-effects-regression.html online textbook, which is mostly designed for those around my level. I have found other pages (eg https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/clubSandwich/vignettes/panel-data-CRVE.html) which deal with something like my topic, as well as some answers on this site (eg https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10017/standard-error-clustering-in-r-either-manually-or-in-plm). But I am a beginner at best, and many of the posts quickly get beyond what I can understand or modify to use on my own. I apologize if this is an idiot question.

Comment: Looks more like a request to discuss theory. Might get better answers at CrossValidated.com or on the mixed effects R mailing list.

Comment: I'm not near the point of discussing theory. I'm just asking how to do the regressions I need to do, or if I've got these ones right.

Comment: Well, I suppose it's always good to wait a while before reposting to another list so you won't be guilty of cross-posting. I don't understand why you didn't post on stats.stackexchange.com (=CrossValidated.com), since you are clearly aware of its existence and found relevant prior work there.